# browser cannot connect to websockets

Tags: javascript, nginx

The problem is that when connecting via postman, everything works, but when I go to my domain, an error occurs when connecting.

Nginx:

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.com;
  
  location /ws {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }

 ssl settings...

}
```

Js:

```
let websocket = new WebSocket(`wss://mydomain.com/ws/status/`, [access])
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: “An error”? What error?

Comment: what is the value of `access`

Comment: websocket connection to "wss://mydomain.com..." failed in browser, postman is ok

Comment: Please provide the full error [inside](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78146273/edit) the question - [ask]

Comment: Jaromanda X, token

Comment: and the websocket server expects that value?

Comment: yes, everything worked during development

Comment: `when connecting via postman, everything works, but when I go to my domain, an error occurs` to be clear, you use the same URL in postman as you do from your web page?

Comment: Also, please show the EXACT error in the question like you've been asked twice - it's unlikely the error is simply `websocket connection to "wss://mydomain.com..." failed in browser`

Comment: and furthermore - which browser is failing? have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I'll try to remove [access] and let you know the result

Comment: why? it works in postman, apparently

Comment: I think there is not enough information to point out the problem. I suggest to forget about postman and focus on the browser. Are you sure the protocol is wss? Are you sure the port is correct ? (check with ss -natp on server side) Do you have log files ?  Also, which ip are you connecting? Against localhost or network card?